# How to reliably run a specific git branch version of a bash script?

Tags: bash, git, branching-and-merging

I have a script `loop.sh` that every few hours runs another script `task.sh`. They are both part of the same git repository.

Currently, I run in a sperate `screen` instance (i.e. its own `bash` process)

```
(main) user@computer:repo-dir > ./loop.sh
```

where `loop.sh` can be be thought of as something like:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
   ./task.sh
   sleep 3h
done
```

I have recently made modifications to `task.sh` in VS Code and they were being automatically saved by the program. This made the `loop.sh` pick up a broken version of `task.sh` and fail.

If I were to switch from the `main` git branch to a a new `new-feature` branch to make modifications on `task.sh`, **how do I reliably have both `loop.sh` and its calls to `task.sh` use the `main` version of the files?**

1. Some not very confident sources told me that just running
   `loop.sh` in `main`, the `task.sh` will also be automatically `main`?
2. Some sources were quite confident that including `git checkout main` in the `loop.sh` is wrong. Is that true and why?
3. I've seen a

```
git show main:task.sh | bash
```

Can this be used as a drop in replacement?  The original `./task.sh` takes in arguments, I'm sometimes processing the outputs of the scripts pipe.

Comment: Why aren't you using a cron job?

Comment: Write a script that **1** pulls the scripts from the branch you want 
**2** run them locally on the computer you want.  And @Paolo is right, your loop script could be a cron configuration that calls task.sh.

Comment: A Git working directory should be for the use of the developer, not the end user of the script being developed. *Install* the script properly, and you can execute it regardless of what happens in the Git working directory (or the repository as a whole).

Comment: Hi, this is only an illustrative example of how task.sh gets called. In reality, task.sh is a script that downloads data from a server, and it takes about 3h to get to the front of the queue.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I reliably have both loop.sh and its calls to task.sh use the main version of the files?

Let the scripts run in a separate [worktree](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-worktree/info). That way you can work on `new-feature` or whatever branch you want in your main worktree without disturbing your scripts.

```
cd $HOME/repo-dir
git worktree add -b main.mirror ../scripts-worktree main
```

And update `loop.sh` to

```bash
cd "$HOME/scripts-worktree"
git switch main.mirror

for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
   git merge main
   ./task.sh
   sleep 3h
done
```

(although as others have mentioned triggering it from cron is a better option).

Answer (score 1):

> I've seen a
>
> ```
> git show main:task.sh | bash
> ```
>
> Can this be used as a drop in replacement?

Yes. If you want to pass arguments you can

```
git show main:task.sh | bash /dev/stdin arg1 arg2 arg3
```